# Iptables: Two IP-Adresses, allow Port 3306 just for one

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, iptables

my server has two ip's:

```
# IP one: 192.168.45.1 (allow MYSQL on Port 3306)
# IP two: 192.168.45.2 (disallow MYSQL on Port 3306)
```

.

how can i configure **iptables**, to drop incoming connections for a specific IP and allow it to the other?

.

```
#
# Allow MYSQL-Port only for 192.168.45.1!
#

 /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp 192.168.45.1 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
 /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp 192.168.45.2 --dport 3306 -j DROP

# END SCRIPT
```

this seems not to work.. :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 192.168.45.1 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 192.168.45.2 --dport 3306 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 6):

Rather than enforcing this at the firewall level, have MySQL bind to 192.168.45.1 with the [bind-address](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) option. Add this to `/etc/my.cnf`:

```
bind-address=192.168.45.1
```

Comment: I thought this didn't allow localhost connections though.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi looks like localhost connections are allowed always plus the ip which you specify for bind-address. That's how it works on my machine.